# Email verification after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, email-validation

I tried using devise gem following this : http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/ it doesn't tell us how to send email verification mail. i read this : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise too but didn't really understand it. so i am making my own verification.

1. make hash from user email and salt.
2. send that hash to user email using mailer
3. ask user to enter the hash sent to his email and if matches then user account is verified.

how bad implementation of email verification is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily using Devise, all you need is to add `Confirmable` module to devise, refer to this official devise solution to tackle this thing

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users)

Comment: i followed this: http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/ and then this : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users and didn't recieve any conformation email. i am assuming i am suppose to make some other configuration changes too?

Comment: Have you added email configuration?

Comment: i found all i needed here : http://bladeronline.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/setting-2-step-confirmation-using-devise-in-rails/ thanks for you help anyway.